# Program to display data in a hierarchically form (similar to CRM systems)

Tags: information-management

I want an easier way to list data for all the companies we work for and to easily search through that data

So I want to list all the companies we work for that to lead into a sub directory were I can list all the computers they have and if I click on an individual computer I can see other data about that machine.
I want to be able to search through this data so if I wanted to search every machine that has Windows XP I could easily bring that up.

Comment: On what OS must this run? What is your price limit (in case it comes to paid software)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Simitless. It is a platform that enables you to create your own information system/data management app. It gives you modules/fields (like spreadsheet columns) that you can select from and tailor the app to track/collect only the data you need.

- You can create the "hierarchical" style of app where individual computers that themselves are contained in one data type "Computer" can link to another data type "Company" that contains data about all the companies. Like here:

  [image]
- Clicking on the names of computers in the utmost right column will lead you to the table containing all the data about this computer.
- You can search and filter the information as you want.
- Your app is online, always accessible and you can have multiple people (like your coworkers) working on the same document at the same
  time.
- You can import and export your data at any time, so there is no problem with that either.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We launched recently and are still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand. Just get in touch. (If you want to have a look, I have made a [Hardware Tracker Template](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-hardware-tracker) according what you have described that you would like to track. And, since it is just a template, you can take it as a basis and modify it to your heart's desire.) It might be just what you are looking for. And let me know how it goes, if you decide to give it a go.